# I can't seem to get the LSTM to compile as I can't get the right size. from the np.array I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

Here is the main code

This is getting everything set up for the Mp hands

```
# Create an instance of Mphands and define parameters for it
mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands(static_image_mode=False,
                      max_num_hands=1,
                      model_complexity=0,
                      min_detection_confidence=0.4)
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

# Initialize the time
pTime = 0
cTime = 0

# Create DataPath for Database
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
print(currentDirectory)
# Create list of actions we want
actions = np.array(['down'])
# 30 frames with 30 videos
numSequences = 30
seqLength = 30

sequences, labels = [], []
labelMap = {label: num for num, label in enumerate(actions)}

# Create a folder for each one of the actions and subfolder for each sequence
for action in actions:
    for sequence in range(numSequences):
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(currentDirectory, 'MP_Data', action, str(sequence)))
        except:
            pass
```

This is where the arrays get set within this loop
for action in actions:
for sequence in range(numSequences):
for frame_num in range(seqLength):
allLandmarkPts = []
# Get the frame from the video stream
success, img = cap.read()

```
            # get the current time to calculate fps
            cTime = time.time()
            
            # define the image parameter
            img = imutils.resize(img, width = 1200, height = 1000)
            (image_height, image_width, _) = img.shape
            imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            results = hands.process(imgRGB)
            
            # If there is a hand detected, get the coordinates for Index, Ring, and Middle Fingers
            if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                for (idx, hand_landmarks) in enumerate(results.multi_hand_landmarks):
                    indexCoords = \
                        (hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].x
                            * image_width,
                            hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].y
                            * image_height)
                    middleCoords = \
                        (hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP].x
                            * image_width,
                            hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP].y
                            * image_height)
                    ringCoords = \
                        (hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.RING_FINGER_TIP].x
                            * image_width,
                            hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.RING_FINGER_TIP].y
                            * image_height)
                    
                    # Append the coordinates to arrays for contrails
                    indexPts.appendleft((int(indexCoords[0]), int(indexCoords[1])))
                    middlePts.appendleft((int(middleCoords[0]), int(middleCoords[1])))
                    ringPts.appendleft((int(ringCoords[0]), int(ringCoords[1])))
                    
                    allLandmarks = np.array([hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].x
                            * image_width,
                            hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].y
                            * image_height,
                            hand_landmarks.landmark[mpHands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].z]).flatten()
                    allLandmarkPts.append(allLandmarks)
            
                   
            
            # Start the data collection
            if frame_num == 0:
                cv2.putText(img, "Starting Collection", (600, 500),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 4, cv2.LINE_AA)
                # Display the livestream
                cv2.imshow("Image", img)
                # Gives you 3 seconds to reset where you want to be
                cv2.waitKey(1000)
            else:
                cv2.putText(img, "Grabbing collection for sequence " + str(sequence), (500, 400),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 4, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.imshow("Image", img)

            # Get the path for where we want to save the data and save it
            collectionPath = os.path.join(currentDirectory, 'MP_Data', action, str(sequence), str(frame_num))
            np.save(collectionPath, allLandmarkPts)
    
        # Wait for user to press q to quit the program
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# iterate through the data and associate it wit the albels
for action in actions:
    for sequence in range(numSequences):
        window = []
        for frame_num in range(seqLength):
            res = np.load(os.path.join(currentDirectory, 'MP_Data', action, str(sequence), "{}.npy".format(frame_num)))
            # print(np.shape(res))
            window.append(res)
        sequences.append(window)
        labels.append(labelMap[action])
 
a = np.array(sequences)
x = a[:,:,0,:].reshape(900,3)
print(np.shape(x))
y = to_categorical(labels).astype(int)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.5)

log_dir = os.path.join(currentDirectory, 'Logs')
tb_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
```

The model that I'm using is Sequential, but I don't really know what the input shape is or how I'm supposed to figure it out.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(30,1662)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences = True, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation= 'softmax'))

res = [.7, 0.2, 0.1]
actions[np.argmax(res)]
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 2000, callbacks=[tb_callback])


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```